# PHP. Преобразование даты. Добавить количество дней

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Нужно преобразовать дату.
Получаем из БД дату в виде

```
[date_time1] => 2016-10-05
```

Нужно добавить к этому определенное количество дней!
Например 5 дней чтобы получить

```
[date_time1] => 2016-10-10
```

Это же добавляет от текущей даты?

```
mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-10-05');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Answer (score 3):

и как добавление к ответу @Firepro можно использовать strtotime()

```
$now = strtotime('2016-10-05');
$plus5day = strtotime('+5 day',$now);
echo date('Y-m-d',$plus5day);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "2016-10-05";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 day", strtotime($data)));
```

// результат 2016-10-10

Comment: Ну какая же $data - если $date. Соблюдайте культуру называния переменных) $data - так называют данные.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вот более бородатый способ, чтобы не запоминать лишнего, вроде `+5 day`

```
$date = "2016-10-05";
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) + 5*86400 ); /*в дне 86400 секунд - обычно все это помнят*/
```

Comment: Чтобы ничего лишнего не запоминать, нужно писать 5 * 24 * 60 * 60.

Comment: В любом случае, "+5 day" намного понятней при чтении чужого кода.

Comment: @Mrak не согласен. +5 day - двойной вызов функции - когда можно одним обойтись, во вторых лишняя логика (надо запоминать синтаксис). А `86400`  - помнят все.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр мне стыдно я не помню, хотя если грубо сказать это звучит на подобие - все помнят число пи до 16-той цифры.

Comment: @Mrak помнят - потому что видят в коде это каждый день. Потому что этот способ наиболее популярен) Не знаю - что правильнее, добавил способ, который сам вижу чаще всего и к которому привык. И помоему он проще, чем вложенный `strtotime`